# Ordering records in descending and ascending order in room db

Tags: android

I'm having issues ordering the data in my room db , basically when i list all records from room db to adapter ,  i have two params according to which i order data , date and time , i want to order data  according to date in descending order and according to time in ascending order , this is my query

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM sporttable ORDER BY model_date DESC")
  List<Model> listAll();
```

what i want to achieve is something like this

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM sporttable ORDER BY model_date DESC AND ORDER BY modul_time ASC")
 List<Model> listAll();
```

basically order my records with two paramaters in the same query is that possible if not , can you please help me , cause i even tried putting duplicate queries but that's not allowed , trying JOIN AND BETWEEN Operators but none of them worked as a red line shows up under when i write them in the query . thank you